# How can I pass a hash into a class_eval'ed method with Ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to mock the OpenID handling in my cucumber tests. For this purpose I use the following method:

```
def set_result_of_openid_authentication(result_type, profile_data = nil)
  ActionController::Base.class_eval "
    def begin_open_id_authentication(identity_url, options = {})
      yield [OpenIdAuthentication::Result.new('#{result_type}'.to_sym), identity_url, #{profile_data}]
    end
  "
end

# example usage
set_result_of_openid_authentication :successful, 'email' => 'dhofstet@example.com'
```

This works fine with Ruby 1.9.2, but with Ruby 1.8.7 I get the following compile error:

```
(eval):5:in `set_result_of_openid_authentication': compile error
(eval):3: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting kDO or '{' or    '('    
...identity_url, emaildhofstet@example.com]
```

For some reason the hash is not preserved... Is there some workaround to make it work with both Rubies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that inside your `class_eval` the interpolated string `#{profile_data}` is coming through as `emaildhofstet@example.com` which is the `to_s` representation of a `Hash` in 1.8.7.

If you replace this with `#{profile_data.inspect}` then it should come come through as `{'email' => 'dhofstet@example.com'}` as required.